# Devise invitation generate accept_invitation_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

I'm using Devise invitable for invitation. Typically, in the invitation email there will be a link to redirect the invitee to the sign_in page, some url like this

```
mywebsite.com/users/invitation/accept?invitation_token=J-azZ8fKtkuAyp2VZWQX
```

This url comes from invitation_instructions.html:

```
<p><%= link_to 'Accept invitation', accept_invitation_url(@resource, :invitation_token => @token) %></p>
```

Now I want to return the invitation url in my controller as json response, something like this:

```
def invite
  invitee = User.invite!({:email => email}, current_user)
  accept_invitation_url = ....
  render :json => accept_invitation_url
end
```

any idea how to get the accept_invitation_url in the controller? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try to include the url helpers module in your controller:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  include DeviseInvitable::Controllers::UrlHelpers

  def invite
    invitee = User.invite!({:email => email}, current_user)
    render :json => accept_invitation_url(invitee, :invitation_token => invitee.token)
  end
end
```

The URL Helper module for the Devise Invitable Gem can be found [here on github](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/master/lib/devise_invitable/controllers/url_helpers.rb)

Ok the raw invitation token is not accessible by default because it's a instance variable without accessor ([source](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/master/lib/devise_invitable/model.rb#L203)), there are two ways you could solve this.

The ugly way, without modifying your model class:

```
  def invite
    invitee = User.invite!({:email => email}, current_user)
    raw_token = invitee.instance_variable_get(:@raw_invitation_token)
    render :json => accept_invitation_url(invitee, :invitation_token => raw_token)
  end
```

The clean way, by adding an attribute reader to your user model class:

```
# User Model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_reader :raw_invitation_token
  # rest of the code
end

# In your controller
def invite
  invitee = User.invite!({:email => email}, current_user)
  raw_token = invitee.raw_invitation_token
  render :json => accept_invitation_url(invitee, :invitation_token => raw_token)
end
```

Update (16th October 2015):

It seems like the UrlHelper module has been removed and the invitation is handled as a normal route, so you can remove the `include DeviseInvitable::Controllers::UrlHelpers` and replace the `accept_invitation_url` call with:

`Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.accept_invitation_url(invitee, :invitation_token => raw_token)`

Comment: thanks sled, the url looks good but I guess we need the raw invitation token here, not the persisted one. Any idea how to get the raw invitation token?

Comment: It do not works for latest `DeviseInvitable` version, ```DeviseInvitable::Controllers::UrlHelpers``` does not exists.
https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/commit/74af11d00a6e79fac6cab30c5685477dfc4ae54c
It was removed

Comment: @NishutoshSharma thanks for the hint, I think they now implemented it as normal route here: https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/efa419a9bfc0e39546187c7747f34a157c022f02/lib/devise_invitable/routes.rb so you can try to use `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.accept_invitation_url(invitee, :invitation_token => raw_token)`

Answer (score 1):

I found out that to use `accept_invitation_url` outside the standard invitation mailer view you need to include inside the mailer the following helper:

```
include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers
```

I tried `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.accept_invitation_url(invitee, :invitation_token => raw_token)` but it is not working.